# Hide/show div with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide and show a div when the link in inside the `a li` tag is clicked, however I can't get the DOM element.
Ousite the ul >li the script it working fine

```
  <a class="showSingle " >All Test </a> //Work Fine
```

```js
$(function() {
  //   $('.showSingle ul.list-inline li a').click(function () {
  $('.showSingle ').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.targetDiv ').slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
  <li>
    <a class="showSingle">View next </a><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
  </li>
```

i have add jsfiddler to explain the hole issue https://jsfiddle.net/mpef13qu/4/

Comment: what happens if you try this line in your console? ````$('.showSingle ')````

Comment: @ErcanPeker  My target div is outside the ul

Comment: if it's outside the ul it's not a sibling

Comment: @Pixelomo No error in console   if the is your Q this is working fime outside the ul >li

Comment: so it returns the div with its attributes?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think it should solve it for good now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong, you were just missing the target :/

UPDATE: I've changed the code snippet

```js
$(function () {
    $('.showSingle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents("ul")
               .siblings('.targetDiv')
               .slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="list-inline text-center">
     <li>
        <a class="showSingle">View next </a>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
     </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="targetDiv" style="display: none">Some text</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list-inline text-center">
     <li>
        <a class="showSingle">View next </a>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
     </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="targetDiv" style="display: none">Some text</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list-inline text-center">
     <li>
        <a class="showSingle">View next </a>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
     </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="targetDiv" style="display: none">Some text</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list-inline text-center">
     <li>
        <a class="showSingle">View next </a>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
     </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="targetDiv" style="display: none">Some text</div>
</div>

<div>
  <ul class="list-inline text-center">
     <li>
        <a class="showSingle">View next </a>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
     </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="targetDiv" style="display: none">Some text</div>
</div>
```

here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jmxto64b/1/)

Comment: thanks but in your code the div is inside the ul >li element . in my it is outside i think this is the prob.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni please check my answer

Comment: @Pixelomo i did , as i was comment . im using mutli divs and it is showing all instead of each

Answer (score 1):

If the target is outside the ul it's not a sibling it's more like an uncle or something ;) so `$(this).siblings` wont work

Try this:

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.targetDiv').slideToggle('fast')
})
```

**Updated answer based on your markup**

Since you have multiple toggle triggers and you only want to toggle the target directly after a certain trigger you can make use of `$(this)`

But you need to chain a few other jQuery functions to get up to the level where you can target the next target.

`$('this').parent().parent().next('.targetDiv')`

`.next()` is better than `.siblings()` in this situation since it returns the next sibling matching the `.targetDiv` selector

Here's the complete code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.showSingle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('this').parent().parent().next('.targetDiv').slideToggle('fast');
    });
 });
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ywsmgd5c/

Comment: It is working fine as you have suggested , the problem is that i have to use siblings  because i have multi divs (it is running in a foreach loop

Comment: so I've answered the question you posted here? but actually the problem is a bit more complex? please create a https://jsfiddle.net so we can see what you mean

Comment: ,thanks,  The jsfiddler is not working & not on my side to

Comment: `$('this')` should be `$(this)`

Comment: oh yep, derp... :)

Comment: @PloniAlmoni please check my answer now, it's working, give me an upvote if you're feeling generous ;)

Answer (score -1):

For not reloading page `<a href="#">` must be written.
I've made [demo](https://codepen.io/raliev/pen/wYgyKP) for you, see it, @Ploni Almoni

Comment: <a href="#"> is making the page just

Comment: @PloniAlmoni, demo doesn't work or do not the same, that you want?